# Where can I find "aligned" environment documentation?

Tags: align, tutorials

Where can I find "aligned" environment documentation? I tried on the web and in this site but I've not been able to find it.

Comment: In the documentation of `amsmath`, more precisely all these environments are documented in `amsldoc.pdf`.

Comment: in `amsmath` documentation. then https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: in most tex distributions you can just issue the command `texdoc amsmath`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's also documented in the LaTeX Companion (not at hand now).

Comment: Where and/or how did you perform your online search? If I type "latex aligned user guide" in a Google search box, the top results are all links to the user guide of the LaTeX package that provides the `aligned` environment.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi how is Mico blaiming your question? We legitimately would like to know what people searched for when their search failed to find, so we can work on improving search results. A lot of people forget to start their google search with latex, when they search LaTeX related stuff online, then, yes, you often fail since Google does not know the context.

Comment: @Mico Ok, I'm sorry. Of course I typed "latex aligned doc" and so on... But I expected to find more accurate doc. I was searching for an `aligned` option ([b]) that I saw in this site. I've not been able to find it in `amsmath` doc so I thought that there was a more accurate doc somewhere.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi interesting, I cannot find that option in the manual either. I'll notify the team behind the manual

Comment: It is mentioned in the manual, on page 8: "Like the `array` environment, these `-ed` variants also take an optional `[t]` or `[b]` argument to specify vertical positioning."

Comment: It would have been quite helpful if you had stated up-front that you had, in fact, already found the user guide of the `amsmath` package and that you were aware that the `aligned` environment is discussed in that user guide, and that you were now looking for a thorough explanation of how to go about using the `aligned` environment's `[t]` and `[b]` placement options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `aligned` environment is from the `amsmath` package, and as such the documentation of `amsmath` is the first place to look. As David says, most users will have the documentation of the packages installed with their TeX distribution, so you can execute

```
texdoc amsmath
```

in a terminal/command prompt to open `amsldoc.pdf`.

The description of `aligned` (and `gathered`, `alignedat`) is found in section 3.7 *Alignment building blocks*, which start on the bottom of page 7. On the middle of page 8, the optional arguments to these environments are described:

> Like the `array` environment, these `-ed` variants also take an optional `[t]` or `[b]` argument to specify vertical positioning.

A quick example demonstrating the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Text $\begin{aligned} a \\ b \\ c \end{aligned}$ text
$\begin{aligned}[b] a \\ b \\ c \end{aligned}$ text
$\begin{aligned}[t] a \\ b \\ c \end{aligned}$ text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information here: [Mathmode.pdf](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf), more precisely at chapter 25 (page 46). But watch out, there is an obsolescence warning at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode):

> The au­thor con­sid­ers this pack­age now as be­ing too old and af­flicted with too many ty­po­graph­i­cal bugs. That’s why it has been clas­si­fied as “ob­so­lete”, at least for the time be­ing.